# explain App.Router.map in emberjs code

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes

While going through the emberjs sample code, i came across this piece of code

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    "use strict";
    this.route("channelr", {path: "/:url"});
    this.route("postr", {path: "/:channel/:url"});
});
```

Can any one explain with example what this actually means, especially the `url` thing

Answer (score 1):

The configuration object `path` value is a string that the router uses to match a pattern.  When the name starts with a colon (`:`), it is a placeholder for a variable.  So if the user visited "/123", the `ChannelrRoute` would be used and the `model` function would be passed a parameter with an attribute named `url`.